# Writing filename of file into itself Linux/fedora.

Tags: linux, shell, fedora

I've a little dilemma right now and I'm writing a small shell script that creates 10 files, and then within each file its file name is written.

This is what I have so far:

```
for f in {0..9}.txt
do
    echo Hello, this is the first line of '#$f' > "File${f}"

done
```

So output for each file should be:

```
Hello, this is the first line of file0 

Hello, this is the first line of file1
```

etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use single quotes, the shell will not expand what is inside them. So `'#$f'` is treated as literally the string `#$f` instead of being expanded to the value of `$f`. Try this instead:

```bash
for f in {0..9}.txt; do
    echo "Hello, this is the first line of file #$f" > "File${f}"
done
```

Example:

```
$ cat File3.txt
Hello, this is the first line of file #3.txt
```